# Generating a client with Soap 1.2 in php

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Could you tell me if there is a tool to generate a soap client with these requirements:

1. soap 1.2
2. the client is based on three different service (so 3 wsdl)
3. those services have shared types

I found out about:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

and

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

The thing I can't find out searching for it is especially the last two point.
Any help will be appreciated because I can't unserstand how to create it from different sources and how to call a specific service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test my solution as i don't have 2-3 web services running, but i think this solution will work (if i understood you correctly). Please if you can try it and let me know.

```
<?php
class wstest {
    function __construct($url) {
        $this->soapUrl = $url;
        try{
            $this->client = new SoapClient($this->soapUrl,array('login' => 'wsuser', 'password' => "some_password", "connection_timeout"=>30,'trace'=>true,'keep_alive'=>false,'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));
        } catch (Exception $e) {            
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
};

$con = new wstest("http://firstwebservice.com/?wsdl");

$con2 = new wstest("http://secondwebservice.com/?wsdl");

$con3 = new wstest("http://thirdwebservice.com/?wsdl");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked like a charm.

Comment: can you tell me if there's an option to avoid the creation of response wrappers? Like I'm getting AuthTokenResponse with an AuthToken in there. I would like to have the AuthToken directly.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Like my functions all return some form of an ObjectResponse that has as an attribute the Object. For example authorizeUser returns an AuthTokenResponse that contains an AuthToken. That's kinda of redundant. In Java you can tell it do wrap everything in an object that returns directly AuthToken because internally it handles the unwrapping.

Comment: As i understood for example: function returns data (which is object) from which you need only `AuthToken` variable yes? So you can use `get_object_vars` function to push this variables into an array. If you can't do it will be better if you post another question with the structure of returned data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to figure out what you might want to do.

- First: One WSDL === one Service === one SoapClient. You cannot mix two WSDL locations on the Soap client level, but depending on your application, might connect each services' results on a higher level.

  So if you have three WSDL, then you must instantiate three SoapClient classes to be used. It's not like a single generic HTTP Client which can make requests to any existing webserver.
- Second: Unless you provide a classmap to the SoapClient, the return value of any request is only a mixture of stdClass and array. There might be types defined in the WSDL, but PHP does not map them to anything unless you define it.

  I would recommend using a classmap with your own defined classes that match the ComplexType definitions in the WSDL. There are some code generators to be googled that might do the job, but the Soap standard is complex, as is the definitionof WSDL, so you might end up doing work by hand.

  You can perfectly live without a classmap if the data structures are small.
- Third: If the three WSDL share data types, this will not affect PHP in any way. Since without classmap the responses are stdClass and Array, and the Request parameters can be the same, you won't get any benefit from this information.

  If on the other hand you go the way of the classmap, I'd expect that the shared types will lead to the same classes generated, so you would also see on the PHP level that a ComplexType from Service A is identical to the ComplexType of Service B.